# How to pragmatically test that youtube video links is ok

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Here is a link to video which does not work

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abEOkul6HEx

How I can programatically detect this ?
The scenario would be to monitor a list of youtube videos and detect if a single video was deleted or is no longer available

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following youtube v3 API GET request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id&id={VIDEO_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

In the results check for `pageInfo.totalResults` attribute

**Update**

If you want to pass multiple video ids in one API, it also can. `id={VIDEO_ID1},{VIDEO_ID2}`. In this case you can't depend on `pageInfo.totalResults` you have to go through `items[].id` decide.

Comment: Will this work for all videos or only videos uploaded by myself ? I mean can I use this api to get info about videos which I did not published on my account ?

Comment: Thanks I think this will work for me. It's a pity that I can not do a batch query 
with many ids and get statuses for each video

Comment: Just note there are other conditions where the API can return data for a video but the video is still not available for viewing.

Comment: @johnh10 - what are the other conditions ? And is there a way to detect this ?